# Crush on Cubicle neighbor from different team; how should I proceed?

Tags: professionalism, relationships

I have a crush on a girl same age as me whose cubicle literally shares the same wall as mine. She is in a different team. For a couple of weeks now, we have never spoken a single word, despite having walked past each other in the break room a couple of times. We sit a few feet apart, her facing me, but cubicle walls are tall and the entrance to her cubicle is in a different aisle than mine.

I can't really stop thinking about her and my heart rate is quite high all day long as a result. Whenever a colleague comes to discuss something technical with me, being the miserable loser I am, I even go as far as raising my voice in hopes of impressing her somehow.

Even when I get home, I can't help but think about where she is right now and what she is doing. (How would I even know whether she is single?)

What should I do?

Comment: "being the miserable loser I am" The first thing to work on is your self-esteem. No one wants to date someone with this attitude.

Comment: Don't ask her out. Get over it and find someone else somewhere else. The truth is that workplace relationships are a terrible choice for a person to make. The amount of potential problems this could create for both of you is gargantuan. Do not do this. Full stop. If you do, you're being irresponsible with your career and your well being.

Comment: If you ever watched The Office (yes it's satire but it is rather accurate of how office politics works), you'd find out quickly that going out with someone within the same office space can be really complicated. HR will give you a hard time, conflict of interest may occur, if you two break up then there will be a bad work environment for the both of you, the list goes on. I think it's responsible of you to get someone else's advice on here so kudos for trying to seek help rather than making decisions already.

Comment: A nitpick: if she occupies a cubicle as a full-time employee, and is old enough to have a crush on, she is probably a woman, not a girl. More importantly, if you have never spoken and you don't even know whether she's single and/or of an orientation that would include you as an object of affection, then you don't know her at all, and should perhaps get to know her as a human being first.

Comment: @ShinEmperor Actually, the workplace is great to get to know people well and find partners for long term relationships. What the workplace is typically really bad for is trying to start dating out of the blue or directly hitting on someone without knowing them, because that can indeed go wrong easily and then you're stuck with your misstep at work every day (and the other person, too). So in this case, I agree that OP should not do anything hasty and get a more professional attitude / their crush feelings under control first.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> What should I do?

I'd strongly suggest you avoid engaging in romantic relationships with current coworkers. Most of the times it brings more harm than good (specially if it's currently a "crush").

However, that doesn't stop you from being polite and, perhaps, start by introducing yourself or greeting her in the mornings. You know, casual water-cooler talk.

No need to take it to a romantic relationship; why not try to know each other before?

Now, if you can't help and feel you won't be able to have a non-romantic relationship with her, I again strongly suggest you get over your crush as soon as you can and move on.

Comment: +1 This x100. It's just bad karma. Simple as that.

Comment: Not sure if bad karma... but surely a bad idea to do within the same company.

Comment: Bad Karma in the sense that these sorts of things always have a habit of coming back to you when you do them.

Comment: So many reasons, why this is a yes! Perfect answer!

Comment: @ShinEmperor oh, I understand your point now. Yes, this can go wrong in many ways. The only good outcome is if they are truly for each other, get married and live happily ever after... otherwise the relationship will eventually end.

Comment: OP should also check the employee handbook.

Comment: @shoover that would be a good idea, so OP can see if there are restrictions imposed by the company explicitly forbidding this...